# Leaflet snap circle draw to marker

Tags: leaflet, snapping, leaflet-draw

I am looking for ideas/libraries that enable snapping when I create a circle with leaflet draw. There is the libaray [Leaflet snap](https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Snap), that enables  snapping of draggable markers to polylines and other layers. But I am looking for an option to snap to markers when creating a circle. So basically create a circle around the marker.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you find a solution?

I've created a function which does this for me.

```
  function mapToPosition(position){
    lon = position.coords.longitude;
    lat = position.coords.latitude;

    var marker = new L.Marker([lat,lon],{title: "Not at the right spot? Drag me!"}).addTo(map);
    marker.dragging.enable();

    marker.on('dragend', function(e){
      var coords = e.target.getLatLng();
      var lat = coords.lat;
      var lon = coords.lng;
      map.panTo({lon:lon,lat:lat})
      map.removeLayer(cir);
      cir = L.circle([lat,lon],1000).addTo(map).bindPopup("Area within 1km of your point.");
    });

    cir = L.circle([lat,lon],1000).addTo(map);
  }
```

I hope that helps!